# a parallel expectimax

Tags: java, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

Is it possible to make expectimax search parallel? I want to try it on just a basic expectimax algorithm like star1 just to see if there will be significant increase in performance.

What I know right now is to make the alpha-beta pruning parallel similar to the minimax but it's kinda different since chance nodes are involved in expectimax. The problem is I don't know exactly how to do it. I think it's theoretically possible though.

Comment: expectimax without alpha-beta prunning is trivial to parallelize, don't you agree?

Comment: yes, im trying to parallelize expectimax with alpha-beta pruning (star1). I'm just not sure what part of the algorithm should I apply it to.

Comment: when do you think should I apply it to?